# C# count the amount of numbers passed in the loop

Tags: c#, string, for-loop, count, numbers

I'm currently learning C# and I was trying to print out a list of numbers to the console line. The list that I want to have is as followed:

```
01 02 03 04 05
06 07 08 09 10
11 12 13 14 15
etc
```

The only problem that I'm walking against now is that I cant get a new line after 5 numbers are printed.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                if (i < 10)
                {
                    Console.Write(i.ToString("00 "));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(i + " ");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And it prints out:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 etc
```

How can I make it so that after every 5 numbers a new line starts? What kind of loop or statement do I have to use in order to get this to work?

Comment: Just an optimization - you don't need the `if (i < 10)`... you can do `Console.Write(i.ToString("00 "))` for numbers >= 10 as well, and it will print what you want.

Comment: @entropic, Thank you for the optimalization, I implemented this into the code aswell :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach is to check that the number that you have just printed is divisible by five, and print a newline if it is divisible:

```
if (i % 5 == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your program as following

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                if (i < 10)
                {
                    Console.Write(i.ToString("00 "));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(i + " ");
                }
                if (i % 5 == 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```